# PHP arrays: delete duplicates and reorder keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have this array:

```
$gspa['aryNumEmp']
: array = 
  0: string = 41
  1: string = 41
  2: string = 41
  3: string = 41
  4: string = 41
  5: string = 41
  6: string = 41
  7: string = 41
  8: string = 41
  9: string = 2355
  10: string = 2355
  11: string = 2355
  12: string = 2355
  13: string = 2355
  14: string = 2355
```

I want this array without duplicates so I do:

```
array_unique($gspa['aryNumEmp'])
```

And now I have:

```
: array = 
  0: string = 41
  9: string = 2355
```

What do I have to do to get the array keys reordered like that:

```
: array = 
  0: string = 41
  1: string = 2355
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-key the array.

```
$new_array = array_values(array_unique($gspa['aryNumEmp']));
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_unique` has been [benchmarked as slow](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#98453) but that was [prior to PHP7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#120487)

That said, it's *probably* more performant to do `array_keys(array_flip($originalArray))`